# sqlpro duplicate entry error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm just learning sqlpro and I'm completely stumped.

I'm trying to do this:

```
insert into vehicleModel(vehicleModel)
(select distinct(model) from vehicle
order by model);
```

I keep getting this -

> Duplicate entry 'Express 2500 2WD Conversion Ca' for key 'vehicleModel'

If I run this -

```
select * from vehicle
where model = 'Express 2500 2WD Conversion Ca';
```

I get nothing.

Any suggestions?

The table definition is:

```
create table vehicleModel (
   vehicleModelid int not null auto_increment, 
   vehicleModel varchar(30) not null, 
   primary key (vehicleModelid) 
)
engine = InnoDB default charset=latin1;
```

im pulling from here -

```
CREATE TABLE `vehicle` (
  `vehicleId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `make` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cylinders` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `displacement` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `drive` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `eng_dscr` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `trany` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpgHighway` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpgCity` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuelCostAnnual` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuelType` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fuelType1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VClass` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpgh` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mpgc` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`vehicleId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: Not relevant here, but: `distinct` is ***NOT*** a function. It always applies to **all** column in the select list. Writing `distinct(model)` makes no sense.

Comment: Can you show us the definition ov `vehiclemodel` and the definition of its keys and indexes? Also: "sqlpro" seems to be an SQL client tool, not a DBMS. So which DBMS system are you using?

Comment: create table vehicleModel
(vehicleModelid int not null auto_increment,
vehicleModel varchar(30) not null, 
primary key (vehicleModelid)
)engine = InnoDB default charset=latin1;

Comment: Sorry i don't  now how to post the code properly this is my first time on here

Comment: Please do not add code in comments. [Edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35395450/edit) your question

Comment: Shouldn't your query to test the existence be: `select * from vehicle
where vehicleModel = 'Express 2500 2WD Conversion Ca';` Using `vehicleModel` instead of `model` since you are inserting into the `vehicleModel` column?

Comment: vehicleModel doesn't exist because that's what I'm trying to create. I'm wanting to insert into vehicleModel from model. I'm need to use distinct because there is repeats in model because of different years, fuel types, etc.

Comment: I see that - the tables are incorrect as well. You are looking at your source table and not the table you are inserting in to check for the existence. See my answer let me know now if that helps you

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Your text is being truncated to 30 maximum characters. It is likely the case that you have two models within `vehicle.model` that, once truncated, have the same value.**

First check to see if you already have an entry in the table. Your query to check that appears incorrect, so you would use this:

`SELECT * FROM vehicleModel WHERE vehicleModel = 'Express 2500 2WD Conversion Ca';`

It is likely that there is already that record in the table, which is why you cannot insert a duplicate.

You can delete this record or all records within the table and try your insert again, like:

```
DELETE FROM vehicleModel WHERE vehicleModel = 'Express 2500 2WD Conversion Ca';
INSERT INTO vehicleModel (vehicleModel) (SELECT DISTINCT model FROM vehicle ORDER BY model);
```

Comment: I copy/pasted your statements still getting this error -

Comment: Duplicate entry 'Express 2500 2WD Conversion Ca' for key 'vehicleModel'

Comment: can you confirm that the table `vehicleModel` is empty?

Comment: i just deleted/recreated the vehicleModel table and it solved the issue- thank you for the help.

Comment: Take note of my edit regarding the truncation of the text